# Automatically deriving a transformer from a rich case class to a simple case class?

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats

I have a simple case class that represents a pet:

```
case class Pet(name: String, age: Int)
```

Now say I have a case class that has a 1:1 mapping to `Pet`, but where all of the properties have been wrapped in some sort of "resolveable" container or monad:

```
case class ResolveableToPet(name: Future[String], age: Some[Int])
```

The transformation from the latter to the former is quite simple to define:

```
def resolvePet(rPet: ResolveableToPet)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Pet] =
  rPet.flatMap(Pet(_, rPet.age.value))
```

Noticing that Future's `flatMap` and Some's `value` in some sense both "extract the value from within the container", I expect we could define an "extractor" typeclass that could treat them both equally, and thus would allow us – with enough work – to define `resolvePet` generically.

Maybe it would even look roughly something like this after all is said and done:

```
def resolve[R, T](resolveable: R)(implicit resolver: Resolver[R, T]): T =
  resolver.resolve(resoleveable)
```

I feel that this isn't even particularly a difficult or challenging problem, and having worked with cats often enough I'm noticing that this seems to align highly with the tools it provides. Such that I suspect that this has *already been solved* and I simply don't know the name by which to refer to this.

Is there a existing tooling – perhaps in cats, kittens, or scalaz – that solves this problem for me, or maybe simply gets me 75% of the way there?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, can't advice you auto deriving decision but I have one concise and not ugly solution. Take a look at [Chimney](https://github.com/scalalandio/chimney) library - it is very usefull library to make conversions between case classes.
I write a simple example for you purposes but I'm sure, you can easily write another one more complex based on examples from [documentation](https://scalalandio.github.io/chimney/)

```scala
import cats.Semigroupal
import cats.syntax.traverse._
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.instances.future._
import io.scalaland.chimney.TransformerFSupport
import io.scalaland.chimney.dsl._

import scala.collection.compat.Factory
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

case class LiftedFoo(a: Future[Int], b: Option[String])

case class Foo(a: Int, b: String)

// this transformer we write to call withFieldComputedF and pack our result into some Future
implicit val transformerFSupport: TransformerFSupport[Future] = new TransformerFSupport[Future] {
  override def pure[A](value: A) = Future.successful(value)

  override def product[A, B](fa: Future[A], fb: => Future[B]) = Semigroupal[Future].product(fa, fb)

  override def map[A, B](fa: Future[A], f: A => B) = fa.map(f)

  override def traverse[M, A, B](it: Iterator[A], f: A => Future[B])(implicit fac: Factory[B, M]): Future[M] =
    it.toList.traverse(f).map(fac.fromSpecific(_))
}

val foo: Future[Foo] = LiftedFoo(Future(1), Some("z - last"))
  .into[Foo]
  .withFieldComputedF(_.a, _.a)
  .withFieldComputed(_.b, _.b.getOrElse("")) // we can write here some fallback case for None in b field
  .transform

Await.result(event, 1.second) // Foo(1,z - last)
```

You can use same transformerFSupport for the same `F[_]` type and not write a lot of code to simple map case class into another.